# How to add MD5 hash toa PowerShell file dump

Tags: powershell

Looking for a line to add that pulls the file information as below but includes an MD5 hash

It can be from certutil, but there is not a means to download that module so looking for a means that uses PowerShell without an additional update of PowerShell.

We are looking to compare two disks for missing files even when the file might be located in an alternate location.

```
cls
$filPath="G:/"
Set-Location -path $filPath

Get-ChildItem -Path $filPath -recurse |`
foreach-object{ 
$Item=$_
$Path =$_.FullName 

$ParentS=($_.FullName).split("/")
$Parent=$ParentS[@($ParentS.Length-2)]

$Folder=$_.PSIsContainer
#$Age=$_.CreationTime
#$Age=$_.ModifiedDate
$Modified=$_.LastWriteTime
$Type=$_.Extension
$Path | Select-Object `
    @{n="Name";e={$Item}},`
    @{n="LastModified";e={$Modified}},`
    @{n="Extension";e={$Type}},`
    @{n="FolderName";e={if($Parent){$Parent}else{$Parent}}},`
    @{n="filePath";e={$Path}}`
} | Export-csv Q:/lpdi/fileDump.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Possible answer here: (Thanks Guenther)

```
@{name="Hash";expression={(Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -Path $Path).hash}}
```

In this script it meets the filehash condition along with the name of the file which allows a way to find the file on the folder and know it matches another one in another location based on the hash.

I'm not sure what happens on the file hash itself.  If it includes the name of the file, the hash will be different.  If it is only the file itself and the path doesn't matter, it should meet the requirement.  I'm not sure how to include it in the code above however

Comment: there is a commandlet `Get-FileHash` you can use like `Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -Path $filPath).Hash` is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks Guenther. Code above ( @{name="Hash";expression={(Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -Path $Path).hash}} ) inserted. Checking.  Currently with line as edited above, the hash comes back empty.

Answer (score 2):

Your code could be simplified so you don't need all those 'in-between' variables.
Also, the path separator character in Windows is a backslash (`\`), not a forward slash (`/`) which makes this part of your code `$ParentS=($_.FullName).split("/")` not doing what you expect from it.

Try

```
$SourcePath = 'G:\'

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object { 
    # remove the next line if you do not want console output
    Write-Host "Processing file '$($_.FullName)'.."
    $md5 = ($_ | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5).Hash
    $_ | Select-Object @{Name = 'Name';         Expression = { $_.Name }},
                       @{Name = 'LastModified'; Expression = { $_.LastWriteTime }},
                       @{Name = 'Extension';    Expression = { $_.Extension }},
                       @{Name = 'FolderName';   Expression = { $_.Directory.Name }},
                       @{Name = 'FilePath';     Expression = { $_.FullName }},
                       @{Name = 'FileHash';     Expression = { $md5 }}
} | Export-Csv -Path 'Q:/lpdi/fileDump.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Because getting hash values is a time consuming process I've added a Write-Host line, so you know the script did not 'hang'..

Comment: Theo, This is a very clean script and it looks write but I am struggling with it a big - the error is: Exception calling ".ctor" with "0" arguments.  "This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms."   It suspect I can up the algorithm SHA1 - yes I can.  Very nice code Theo.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Okay so, here is my workaround as promised.

Before we start, requirements are:

- Have python 3.8 or above installed and registered in windows PATH
- edit the ps1 file variables accordingly
- edit the python file variables accordingly
- bypass powershell script execution policies

There are 4 files in the working directory (different from your target directory):

- addMD5.ps1 (static)
- addMD5.py (static)
- fileDump-original.csv (auto-generated)
- fileDump-modified.csv (auto-generated)

Here are the contents of those 4 files:

### addMD5.ps1

```
$targetDir="C:\Users\USERname4\Desktop\myGdrive"
$workingDir="C:\Users\USERname4\Desktop\myWorkingDir"
$pythonName="addMD5.py"
$exportName = "fileDump-original.csv"

Set-Location -path $workingDir

if (Test-Path $exportName) 
{
  Remove-Item $exportName
}

Get-ChildItem -Path $targetDir -recurse |`
foreach-object{ 
$Item=$_
$Path =$_.FullName 

$ParentS=($_.FullName).split("/")
$Parent=$ParentS[@($ParentS.Length-2)]

$Folder=$_.PSIsContainer
#$Age=$_.CreationTime
#$Age=$_.ModifiedDate
$Modified=$_.LastWriteTime
$Type=$_.Extension
$Path | Select-Object `
    @{n="Name";e={$Item}},`
    @{n="LastModified";e={$Modified}},`
    @{n="Extension";e={$Type}},`
    @{n="FolderName";e={if($Parent){$Parent}else{$Parent}}},`
    @{n="filePath";e={$Path}}`
} | Export-csv $exportName -NoTypeInformation

python $pythonName
```

### addMD5.py

```
import os, hashlib

def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as fp:
        for i, line in enumerate(fp):
            pass
    return i + 1

def read_nth(fname,intNth):
    with open(fname) as fp:
        for i, line in enumerate(fp):
            if i == (intNth-1):
                return line

def getMd5(fname):
    file_hash = hashlib.md5()
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
        chunk = f.read(8192)
        while chunk:
            file_hash.update(chunk)
            chunk = f.read(8192)
    return file_hash.hexdigest()

file1name = "fileDump-original.csv"
file2name = "fileDump-modified.csv"

try:
    os.remove(file2name)
except:
    pass

file2 = open(file2name , "w")

for linenum in range(file_len(file1name)):
    if (linenum+1) == 1:
        file2.write(read_nth(file1name,linenum+1).strip()+',"md5"\n')
    else:
        innerfilename = read_nth(file1name,linenum+1).split(",")[4].strip()[1:-1]
        file2.write(read_nth(file1name,linenum+1).strip()+',"'+getMd5(innerfilename)+'"\n')

file2.close()
```

### fileDump-original.csv

```
"Name","LastModified","Extension","FolderName","filePath"
"test1.txt","20-Jun-21 12:50:44 PM",".txt","C:\Users\USERname4\Desktop\myGdrive\test1.txt","C:\Users\USERname4\Desktop\myGdrive\test1.txt"
"test2.txt","20-Jun-21 12:50:37 PM",".txt","C:\Users\USERname4\Desktop\myGdrive\test2.txt","C:\Users\USERname4\Desktop\myGdrive\test2.txt"
```

### fileDump-modified.csv

```
"Name","LastModified","Extension","FolderName","filePath","md5"
"test1.txt","20-Jun-21 12:50:44 PM",".txt","C:\Users\USERname4\Desktop\myGdrive\test1.txt","C:\Users\USERname4\Desktop\myGdrive\test1.txt","d659c1bc0a3010b0bdd45d9a8fee3196"
"test2.txt","20-Jun-21 12:50:37 PM",".txt","C:\Users\USERname4\Desktop\myGdrive\test2.txt","C:\Users\USERname4\Desktop\myGdrive\test2.txt","d55749658669d28f8549d94cd01b72ba"
```

Comment: G: drive has roughly 1 Terabyte of data in many many folders.  There is a second drive that we need to compare.   It may have the file in a different directory in the latter.  Q is a location where the csv dump is stored.  CSV is imported to SQL and compared with the information from the other drive.  By comparing the hash, we can tell the file is the same but located in a different directory and not missing.

Comment: Okay, but you already have a possible answer in your latest edit. Seems to me like it would work, wouldn't it?

Comment: Well it should but all the hashes come up blank so I'm not sure what might be wrong.

Comment: @Jamie how about you try my new code (just updated)? I tested it and it works.

Comment: Hi Joshua, your code looks good but I haven't tested it.  I gave you a one up anyway for effort - putting it together in both Python and Powershell goes above and beyond and I laud effort.   I wound up using Theo's code below with the one change from the MD5 to a SHA1 due to the FIPS validation.

Comment: @Jamie glad it worked out for you! cheers